# Customize default "git branch" output format and sorting?

Tags: git, shell, fish

I'd like to be able to write `git branch` and the output (when no other params are passed) would follow my pre-defined sorting and formatting specifications. But is that possible? Now, I know the `--sort` and `--format` params I want to pass. But making them default is the hard part.

I know I can make an alias for that, either a git alias or an alias to my fish shell but those are suboptimal AFAIK:

- fish `abbr` works but fails if I want to pass some other params like `-vv`. Also, expanding 2 rows of format string looks ugly.
- git `alias` works but fails to be a general solution as I would need to use a different command for other branch related tasks

Any suggestions or am I thinking this wrong?

The actual end goal is that `git branch` would always list all local branches sorted by latest `committerdate` and always include some nice to have info about the branches like `gone` or `<>` (ahead/behind) and when the last commit was made. But so that it won't hamper other `git branch` functionality.

Comment: (Git) aliases are the way to go

Comment: Use an alias or shell function. Retrain your fingers not to type `git branch`. (I have been burnt by overly-configurable setups where I have to borrow someone else's machine, or run as super-user, or whatever for a few commands and expect my customizations to hold and... they don't. So I've learned to limit how much I customize even those things that offer customization. Better to get `xyz: command not found` than to accidentally encrypt the drive with an unknown key...)

Comment: Also consider using [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) instead of `git branch` if you need a specific output format. In an alias.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a shell function which catches `git branch`, but passes through any other git invocations unaltered:

```bash
git() {
  if [ "$@" = "branch" ]; then
    git branch --format=yourformat --sort=yoursort
  else
    git "$@"
  fi
}
```